# No 3-element counterexample found

Tags: alloy

I am learning Alloy and was trying to make it find two binary relations `r` and `s`, such that `s` equals the transitive closure of `r`, and such that `s` is not equal to `r`. I suppose I can ask Alloy to do this by executing the following:

```
sig V
{
  r : V,
  s : V
}
assert F { not ( some (s-r) and s=^r ) }
check F
```

Now Alloy 4.2 cannot find a counterexample, although an easy 3-element structure would be the one where `r = {(V0,V1), (V1,V2)}` and `s = r + {(V0,V2)}` obviously.

Can someone explain what is going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Translating your requirement directly:

```
// find two binary relations r and s such that 
// s equals the transitive closure of r ands is not equal to r

run {some r, s: univ -> univ | s != r and s = ^r}
```

This gives an instance as expected. The mistake in your spec is that your declarations restrict the relations to be functions; should instead have

```
sig V {
  r: set V,
  s: set V
  }
```

or

```
sig V {r, s: set V}
```